# Change Excerpt Length for Specific Page ID

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working with a theme that uses the following function to set the post excerpt length on all pages:

```
//excerpt length

if ( !function_exists('custom_excerpt_length')):
    function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) { 
        return 90;
    }

add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );

function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '...';
}

add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');

endif;
```

I added new function:

```
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'so20668477_get_the_excerpt', 10, 1 );
function so20668477_get_the_excerpt( $excerpt )
{
if( is_page( 39370 ) )
    $excerpt = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );

return $excerpt;
}
```

But, it is not working, still showing post excerpt on page 39370.  I am needing to display full length posts on Page ID = 39370 only.  Not sure how to add the condition.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First you should be strongly encouraged to always use curly braces even in situations where they are technically optional.

**Don't do:**

```
if ( condition )
  return false;
```

**Instead do:**

```
if ( condition ) {
  return false;
}
```

**About your question :**

This function `apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );` get the **echo**  of the content not the content, so your condition is correct.
Try this code :

```
if( is_page( 39370 ) ){
    $content = get_the_content();
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    $excerpt = explode("[newpage]", $content);
}

return $excerpt;
```

Or there is another aproach :

```
if( is_page( 39370 ) ){
  ob_start();
  the_content();
  $content = ob_get_clean();
}

 return $excerpt;
```

I hope this solution will help you.